# What is the minimum charging requirements to charge an Iphone 7. Current and Voltage

Tags: iphone

I am building a solar charge and need to know what is the bare minimum voltage and current needed to charge an iphone 7. Even if it slow charges it's okay.

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need 5V.

The trick is going to be supplying the correct amount of current.  1.5A is probably the minimum, but you're not going to "quick charge" with that amount.  To quick charge you need at least 18W or 3.6A of current.

Comment: Would it Charge at all if it was only 44 amps.

Comment: 44 amps?!?  You might want to double check that value.  At that current level, you could quick charge about 8 phones simultaneously